# Better to have one or two databases?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm integrating [punBB](http://punbb.informer.com/) into my existing site.  Is it better to continue using one DB and add the new tables into my current setup or is it better to maintain a second DB for the forum.  I guess my main concern is performance and maintainability.  It seems easier to maintain just one DB but are there performance gains or losses with a second DB?

Comment: it realy depends on what is stored in "primary" database. if there are anything that reltes on users, who could use bb - it's better to have one databse.

Comment: It's not at all uncommon to have separate databases for each "application" associated with your website.  If pubBB has a facility to create its own database or recommends you do so (I didn't look at it closely), you should keep it in its own database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming punbb does like every other forum and prefixes the table names (eg. `punbb_users`, `punbb_messages`, etc.) and you're not going to have any table name collisions, one database should be fine.

As far as performance, that depends on how integrated your setup is. Opening another connection to a separate database may be a little more overhead, however re-using the same connection for normal site intricacies and the forum itself would be more efficient. Once thing you may question is how big your site is and how much traffic it does as not every circumstance makes a new connection negligible.

If it makes sense logically and everything is self-contained, I would probably go with one database. it also makes database backups/restores easier as it's all one entity, but if you're on a hosted provider that may not matter as much to you.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm using a prefix for the new tables so it looks like I'll keep and maintain just one DB :)

Answer (score 0):

it depends on flavor. Some will prefer same Database and put different prefixes to tables something like punbb_, joomla_ et al so that they can have single connection object and have things in place. This make centralizing login an easier task as they can somehow share one users table. However, if they don't share anything (other than being owned by same person and same server may be) I suggest you put them separate.  That will easy backup and make a good organization. But as I said, preference matter.

One note though, if you share the database, be careful not to drop existing tables accidentally, so backup everything. I know it might be in your head but just a remainder!